# MediaPlayer completes after pausing

Tags: android, mp3, media-player

I recently observed a very weird problem with MediaPlayer playing an mp3 file. I'm running this code (`mPlayer` is a MediaPlayer):

```
Log.d(TAG, "Pausing");
try {
    mPlayer.pause();
    Log.d(TAG, "Paused");
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "exception pausing player");
}
```

The weird thing is that if I'm close to the end of the audio file, the player sends a completion notification to my `OnCompletionListener` a short time *after* the above code completes. (I haven't pinned down exactly how close I have to be, but it's on the order of 1/4 second.) For instance, here's a typical logcat output when this occurs:

```
05-27 17:23:43.439: DEBUG/Player(266): Pausing
05-27 17:23:43.487: DEBUG/Player(266): Paused
05-27 17:23:43.838: WARN/Player(266): Audio completed (state=PAUSED)
```

Note that the warning line (logged from my `OnCompletionListener`), comes over 300 ms after the call to `pause()` returned!

The result is that the media player enters the PlaybackCompleted state when I don't expect it. This screws up the behavior of my code (as well as `start()`, which restarts from the beginning instead of playing the last little bit of the file).

This has happened on emulators from 1.6 through 2.3 and on at least one device running 2.2. Does anyone know about this problem and what to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mediaplayer runs in a separate thread and you have to wait until the ui thread and the mediaplayer's thread have synced. So the delay is normal. It may be possible that the player really completes the file because of your pause-command reaching the player too late. Try what happens with a longer audio-file.

Another problem which might come up is other code seeking beyond the end of the track after the pause-command. What's the code of your listener?

Comment: I was afraid of something like that, although 350 ms seems like a huge lag between the app and the media player. The length of the audio file isn't the issue...it's how close to the end the user tries to pause it. (To my ear, it sounds like the audio playback is cut off before the end, but I couldn't say for sure, since there's no problem pausing more than 1/4 sec from the end.) My on-completion listener is very simple: it checks a field that indicates what state my code thinks the player should be in and logs a warning if there's a discrepancy. No other code seeks; I log that, too.

Comment: What happens if the user pauses the audio let's say 5s from the end? What do you here and do you get a completed-call, too?

Comment: Everything behaves as expected. After my posted code completes, I set my internal flag to indicate that I've paused the player, I don't get a completion notification, and when I call start(), it resumes from where it was paused. This only happens when pausing very close to the end of the sound file.

Comment: Then I believe it is like I thought: Because of the delay the audio finishes while you issue the pause-command. Is it a problem for you to handle the case when OnCompleted fires but you are in paused-state?

Comment: It's a problem for the way my code is organized right now, but I'll figure out a way to deal with it. I just didn't know exactly what was happening. I think you hit on it.